# Compact table with correlations in Stata

Tags: stata, correlation

I would like to make a table with correlations between two groups of variables (that is, correlation between each variable in group 1 with each variable in group 2, correlation within variables in the same group I don't need) so that the final table has the first column with names of the first group's variables, and the first row second group's variables, and the table would show correlations between them.

`corr` is giving me a symmetrical matrix with all correlations, and it is not compact and nice for presenting results...

Is there some simple way, or command to do it, or what is the easiest way to get something like this?

Comment: This is, in my view, marginal for SO, a forum for professional and enthuasist programmers, developing their own code. Beginner questions on software like Stata when the problem is not knowing the code in the first place are best posed elsewhere: in this case on Statalist www.statalist.org with many more Stata questions and people active  than here (but including all the people most active here).

Comment: thank  you for answering, and information on statalist ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cpcorr` (SSC) allows display of a matrix with row variables and column variables chosen separately.  You need to install it first and read the help to find out its syntax.

Detailed discussion was given at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1310063-cpcorr-updated-on-ssc-module-for-rectangular-blocks-of-correlations

Here is a simple example:

```
. sysuse auto
(1978 Automobile Data)

. ssc inst cpcorr
```

N.B. varying results depending on whether it has previously been installed

```
. h cpcorr

. cpcorr mpg price  \ weight length
(obs=74)

        weight   length
  mpg  -0.8072  -0.7958
price   0.5386   0.4318

.
```